# jquery calculate the balancing figure

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Sl.No</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Purpose</th>
   <th>Debit</th>
   <th>Credit</th>
   <th>Balance</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>25/05/2018</td>
   <td>received cash</td>
   <td class="payment">0</td>
   <td class="receipt">5000</td>
   <td class="balance">5000</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>26/05/2018</td>
   <td>paid cash</td>
   <td class="payment">200</td>
   <td class="receipt">0</td>
   <td class="balance">4800</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>27/05/2018</td>
   <td>received cash</td>
   <td class="payment">0</td>
   <td class="receipt">1000</td>
   <td class="balance">5800</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>28/05/2018</td>
   <td>paid cash</td>
   <td class="payment">500</td>
   <td class="receipt">0</td>
   <td class="balance">5300</td>   
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I am creating a cash book where (balance is equal to previous day balance plus credit if any minus debit if any)...I could not get this done in jquery I am new to coding and stack overflow...excuse me for any mistakes and could some one please help....

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a write code for me question.

Comment: Don't think JQuery is the correct place to calculate.. You should calculate in MySQL.

Comment: Did you try to make some code?

Comment: there may be a option for user to edit the debit or credit figure in the above table and if he do edit..then whole table would be a mess..
in the above table sl.no's have been generated using jquery @RaymondNijland

Comment: yeah i tried o make some code but those are not working in jquery @StanislavIvanov

Comment: Why not do this on backend rather than on frontend?

Comment: I am really helpless in backend too...any help on this issue would be of great help @Eddie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

Note: `<th>` should be on the `<thead>`

```js
var currentBalance = 0;
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {             //Loop thru each row

  var payment = -$(this).find('.payment').text(); //Get the value of payment and make the value negative number
  var receipt = +$(this).find('.receipt').text(); //Get the value of receipt and make the value positive number

  currentBalance += payment + receipt;           //Just add the values

  $(this).find('.balance').text(currentBalance); //Update .balance

  //Check currentBalance  is less than 0, if it is add the class red
  if (currentBalance < 0) $(this).find('.balance').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

/* For red color */
.red {
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sl.No</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Purpose</th>
      <th>Debit</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>25/05/2018</td>
      <td>received cash</td>
      <td class="payment">0</td>
      <td class="receipt">5000</td>
      <td class="balance"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>26/05/2018</td>
      <td>paid cash</td>
      <td class="payment">200</td>
      <td class="receipt">0</td>
      <td class="balance"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>27/05/2018</td>
      <td>received cash</td>
      <td class="payment">0</td>
      <td class="receipt">1000</td>
      <td class="balance"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>28/05/2018</td>
      <td>paid cash</td>
      <td class="payment">10000</td>
      <td class="receipt">0</td>
      <td class="balance"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Working like a charm...thank you so much @eddie...This little help means a lot to me...Thank you very much...

Comment: one more thing if at any point of time when debit exceeds the balance the resulting figure shall be a negative value then the negative value should have a font color : red..is there anyway to do that @Eddie

Comment: @vamshinewbie I added a class on css and js code. Can you check if it is working?